# How can I download my Google Voice data?

Tags: google-voice

I am dropping a Google Voice number, but I don't want to lose all of the voice messages, transcriptions, and SMS messages I already have.

Is there a way to download my Google Voice data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Google's own [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/) service. For Google Voice, go directly [here](https://www.google.com/takeout/#custom%3avoice).

From [the Data Liberation Blog](http://dataliberation.blogspot.com/2011/09/new-on-menu-google-voice-for-google.html).